# Filter on hold and duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

What if we have such a filter? Now you can't answer a question with the [on hold] or [duplicate] tag. Why not to have a possibility to skip them and see *valid* questions?

Comment: use a search with closed:no? like so: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjson%5d%20closed%3ano&mixed=0

Comment: simply don't click on them and skip them?

Comment: When customlists go live you might have that option: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing?cb=1

Comment: Do you want to be able to answer on hold/duplicate questions or just search for them?

Comment: @AndréKool I want to not see them while being at certaing question tag tabs

Comment: In that case you have your answer in @rene their comment. That option already exists currently. It might be a good idea for you to take a look at [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more search options

Answer (score 3):

Duplicates are **perfectly** valid.  In fact, we keep them around explicitly so that you can see them and get the answer you need - just not in that specific question.

Questions which are put on hold may be reopened if the issues which led them to be put on hold are fixed.

There's no value in filtering out these otherwise valid questions.  Not unless you want to answer them; in that case, you can look into the ["No answers" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) on the question search.